# How to correct this function that only throws exception as of now but I want to return an object as well?

Tags: java, generics, guava

I am trying to override the Preconditions.checkNotNull method which currently doesn't have the ability to take in custom defined exceptions. I am writing my own method so that it begins to take the exception method as well.

The expectation of the method is:

1. Check if passed object is null.
2. If passed object is null, throw an exception of the type passed in
   as parameter.
3. If passed object is not null, return the object itself.

I wrote the following functions:

```
public static < T extends Exception > T checkNotNull(T reference, Class < T > exClass, String errorMessage, Object...args) throws T {
    if (reference == null) {
        generateException(exClass, errorMessage, args);
    }
    return reference;
}

private static < T extends Exception > void generateException(Class < T > exClass, String errorMessage, Object...args) throws T {
    try {
        if (errorMessage == null) {
            throw exClass.newInstance();
        } else {
            throw exClass.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, Object[].class).newInstance(errorMessage, args);
        }
    } catch (InstantiationException | NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

They are defined in a file called ExceptionHandler.java.

But, when I try to call it like this, it fails:

```
ExceptionHandler.checkNotNull(myInputObject, InvalidInputException.class, "The input cannot be null");
```

It shows the following error:

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that List conforms to Exception

Comment: If this is not just some exercise, I recommend using one of the `Objects.requireNonNull(...)` methods instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static <T extends Exception> T checkNotNull(T reference, Class<T> exClass, String errorMessage, Object... args) throws T {
```

This will not allow you to pass an arbitrary class for the second paramter. It has to be the class of the object type you pass in the first parameter. But since you have given the type bound for `T` as exception, it(myInputObject) doesn't fit into the first parameter either.

Change the function declaration as

```
public static <T, X extends Exception> T checkNotNull(T reference, Class<X> exClass, String errorMessage, Object... args) 
        throws X
```

This declares a new type parameter `X` for the exception class to be passed in.